# What are the requirements for each of the finish commands?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

Most finish commands have a few different options for how to get to the next level, and I know that certain actions while fighting will trigger exp towards the next level of a certain type. How can I know how to level each one? Is it trial and error only, or is there someway in game? And what are the requirements for each level of finish commands for each character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It cannot be viewed from within the game, but here is the breakdown for all the finishers for each character. All images and info taken from the [KH Wiki](http://www.khwiki.com/Finish_command_%28KHBBS%29).

### Aqua

[image: Aqua Finishers]

#### Level 1

- **Finish** 
   *Default* 
   Swirling magic orbs that knock enemies up

#### Level 2

- **Heat Slash 1** 
   *Use [Firestorm](http://www.khwiki.com/Firestorm) command style 8 times with Finish equipped* 
   Flaming Spin
- **Magic Pulse 1** 
   *Earn 2000 CP (Command Points) with Finish equipped* 
   Spinning orbs that have a 25% chance to confuse enemies
- **Gold Rush** 
   *Collect 1000 munny with Finish equipped* 
   Jumping slash that drops munny

#### Level 3

- **Heat Slash 2** 
   *Use Firestorm command style 12 times with Heat Slash 1 equipped* 
   Flaming spin
- **Ramuh's Judgment** 
   *Use [Thunderbolt](http://www.khwiki.com/Thunderbolt) command style 12 times with Magic Pulse 1 equipped* 
   Thunder based 4-hit combo
- **Magic Pulse 2** 
   *Earn 3800 CP with Magic Pulse 1 equipped* 
   Spinning orbs that have a 50% chance to confuse or freeze enemies
- **Twisted Hours** 
   *Walk 7000 steps with Magic Pulse 1 or Gold Rush equipped* 
   Strike raid with 50% chance to slow or stop enemies
- **Surprise! 1** 
   *Collect 1400 munny with Gold Rush equipped* 
   Slash that drops munny and hp if prompted button is hit

#### Level 4

- **Magic Pulse 3** 
   *Defeat 350 enemies with Magic Pulse 2 equipped* 
   Spinning orbs that have a 75% chance to confuse, freeze, or blind enemies
- **Heal Strike** 
   *Survive 5 lethal blows with Second Chance or Once More while Magic Pulse 2 is equipped* 
   Spin attack that recovers HP
- **Surprise! 2** 
   *Collect 5200 munny while Twisted Hours or Surprise! 1 is equipped* 
   Slash that drops munny and hp if prompted button is hit

#### Level 5

- **Magic Pulse 4** 
   *Defeat 500 enemies with Magic Pulse 3 equipped* 
   Spinning orbs that stun enemies
- **Explosion** 
   *Earn 6400 CP with Magic Pulse 3 equipped* 
   [KABOOM!!!](http://www.khwiki.com/images/3/37/Explosion_KHBBS.gif) (and stun enemies)
- **Ice Burst** 
   *Use [Diamond Dust](http://www.khwiki.com/Diamond_Dust_%28Command%29) command style 15 times while Magic Pulse 3 is equipped* 
   Spin and blizzard

#### Level 6

- **Teleport Spike** 
   *Defeat 800 enemies while Magic Pulse 4 is equipped* 
   Fire 8 energy orbs at enemies

### Terra

[image: Terra Finishers]

#### Level 1

- **Finish** 
   *Default* 
   Jumping 4-hit combo

#### Level 2

- **Heat Slash 1** 
   *Use Firestorm command style 8 times with Finish equipped* 
   Flaming Spin
- **Rising Rock 1** 
   *Earn 2000 CP (Command Points) with Finish equipped* 
   4-hit combo with 50% chance to stun enemies
- **Gold Rush** 
   *Collect 1000 munny with Finish equipped* 
   Jumping slash that drops munny

#### Level 3

- **Ramuh's Judgment** 
   *Use Thunderbolt command style 12 times with Rising Rock 1 equipped* 
   Thunder based 4-hit combo
- **Rising Rock 2** 
   *Earn 3800 CP with Rising Rock 1 equipped* 
   4-hit combo with 50% chance to stun enemies
- **Twisted Hours** 
   *Walk 7000 steps with Rising Rock 1 or Gold Rush equipped* 
   Strike raid with 50% chance to slow or stop enemies
- **Surprise! 1** 
   *Collect 1400 munny with Gold Rush equipped* 
   Slash that drops munny and hp if prompted button is hit

#### Level 4

- **Dark Star 1** 
   *Defeat 420 enemies with Rising Rock 2 equipped* 
   Spin attack and meteor with 50% chance to stun or blind enemies
- **Heal Strike** 
   *Survive 5 lethal blows with Second Chance or Once More while Rising Rock 2 is equipped* 
   Spin attack that recovers HP
- **Random End** 
   *Walk 8000 steps while Twisted Hours or Surprise! 1 is equipped* 
   Random attack with 50% chance to inflict status effect
- **Surprise! 2** 
   *Collect 5200 munny while Twisted Hours or Surprise! 1 is equipped* 
   Slash that drops munny and hp if prompted button is hit

#### Level 5

- **Dark Star 2** 
   *Defeat 550 enemies with Dark Star 1 equipped* 
   Spin attack and 3 meteors with 50% chance to stun or blind enemies
- **Explosion** 
   *Earn 6400 CP with Dark Star 1 equipped* 
   KABOOM!!! (and stun enemies)

#### Level 6

- **Demolition** 
   *Earn 10,000 CP while Dark Star 2 is equipped* 
   5 targeted explosions with 50% chance to stun

### Ven

[image: Ven Finishers]

#### Level 1

- **Finish** 
   *Default* 
   Quick 5-hit combo

#### Level 2

- **Heat Slash 1** 
   *Use Firestorm command style 8 times with Finish equipped* 
   Flaming Spin
- **Air Flair 1** 
   *Earn 2000 CP (Command Points) with Finish equipped* 
   4-hit spin with 25% chance to stun
- **Gold Rush** 
   *Collect 1000 munny with Finish equipped* 
   Jumping slash that drops munny

#### Level 3

- **Ramuh's Judgment** 
   *Use Thunderbolt command style 12 times with Air Flair 1 equipped* 
   Thunder based 4-hit combo
- **Air Flair 2** 
   *Earn 4000 CP with Air Flair 1 equipped* 
   6-hit spin with 50% chance to stun
- **Twisted Hours** 
   *Walk 7000 steps with Air Flair 1 or Gold Rush equipped* 
   Strike raid with 50% chance to slow or stop enemies
- **Surprise! 1** 
   *Collect 1400 munny with Gold Rush equipped* 
   Slash that drops munny and hp if prompted button is hit

#### Level 4

- **Air Flair 3** 
   *Walk 4500 steps with Air Flair 2 equipped* 
   8-hit spin with 50% chance to stun
- **Heal Strike** 
   *Survive 5 lethal blows with Second Chance or Once More while Air Flair 2 is equipped* 
   Spin attack that recovers HP
- **Surprise! 2** 
   *Collect 5200 munny while Twisted Hours or Surprise! 1 is equipped* 
   Slash that drops munny and hp if prompted button is hit

#### Level 5

- **Air Flair 4** 
   *Walk 7000 steps with Air Flair 3 equipped* 
   10-hit spin and stun
- **Explosion** 
   *Earn 6400 CP with Air Flair 3 equipped* 
   KABOOM!!! (and stun enemies)
- **Celebration** 
   *Collect 7000 munny with Surprise! 2 equipped* 
   [Make it rain](http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/135556/make-it-rain-guys.gif) (also 50% item drop increase from targeted enemy)

#### Level 6

- **Stratosphere** 
   *Defeat 800 enemies while Air Flair 4 is equipped* 
   Leaping strikes